# Exporting excel to html using php on windows

Tags: php, com, export, excel-2007

I am using xampp/wamp on windows and looking to convert an excel workbook to a html file.

I am not asking this question right away, i did a lot of research and finally managed to get to a point and got stuck here.

Am using php's COM library to open excel, then read a workbook and try to save it as html, how ever i am having issues with it

This is my code

```
    $excel = new COM("Excel.Application",NULL,CP_UTF8) or die("Unable to instantiate Excel");
    $excel->Application->Visible=1;
    $excel->DisplayAlerts="False";
    $workBook=$excel->Workbooks->Open(realpath("./example-03e-02.xlsx"));
     $workBook->PublishObjects->Add(xlSourceSheet, "c:\\temp\\x.htm", "Sheet1", "", xlHtmlStatic, "test_27778", "");
 $workBook->Publish (True);
 $workBook->AutoRepublish(0);
    $excel->Workbooks->Close();
    $excel->Application->Quit();
    $excel = null;
    $workBook=null;
```

The PUlishObjects method keeps telling me that xlSourceSheet is not defined, i tried to pass it as a string "xlSourceSheet" but it keeps saying parameter type mismatch in one or the other. IN the above case, it says parameter 6 type mismatch;

if i remove the optional parameters like divid and title (the last 2) it shows a type mismatch on source range which empty obviously since am exporting a sheet.

Any body can shed some light on this and tell me what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anywyas, i managed to sort out the problem with some further digging into excel developer manual.

I just had to replace xlSourceSheet and xlHtmlstatic with their respective numbers that i found in the docs. xlSourceSheet is 1 and xlHtmlStatic is 0.

If anybody is looking for these codes, here they are

xlSourceAutoFilter  3   An AutoFilter range
xlSourcePivotTable  6   A PivotTable report
xlSourcePrintArea   2   A range of cells selected for printing
xlSourceQuery   7   A query table (external data range)
xlSourceRange   4   A range of cells
xlSourceSheet   1   An entire worksheet
xlSourceWorkbook    0   A workbook

xlHtmlCalc  1   Use the Spreadsheet component. Deprecated in Excel 2007.
xlHtmlChart 3   Use the Chart component. Deprecated in Excel 2007.
xlHtmlList  2   Use the PivotTable component. Deprecated in Excel 2007.
xlHtmlStatic    0   Use static (noninteractive) HTML for viewing only.

```
$object=$excel->ActiveWorkbook->PublishObjects->Add(1,"c:\\temp\\x.htm","Sheet1",0)->Publish(1);
```

Thanks cweiske :)